# If $k$ is a field then $\text{End}_k(k^2)$ is simple

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. I have to show that $\text{End}_k(k^2)$ is simple.

First of all, I don't see why this is true. For example, if $k=\mathbb{C}(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ then $\varphi\colon k^2\rightarrow k^2$ defined by $(f(x_1,x_2,\dots),g(x_1,x_2,\dots))\mapsto (f(x_2,x_3,\dots),g(x_2,x_3,\dots))$ is a homomorphism, but it is not surjective, so $\varphi\notin \text{End}_k(k^2)^*$, the $*$ denotes all the invertible elements. So the ideal generated by $\varphi$ is not trivial or the whole ring.

I don't know why this statement should be true now. Perhaps my counterexample is flawed, or something else. Could you help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: The map you suggest is not $k$-linear.  For example, the element $(1, 0)$ goes to $(1, 0)$ but $x_1 \cdot (1, 0)$ goes to $x_2 \cdot (1, 0)$.

Comment: @Jez thanks! I now see why the statement is true. It seems that I didnt know the definition of $\text{End}_k()$ precisely.

Comment: Note that just because the two-sided ideal generated by an element is the entire ring does not imply that the element is invertible when the ring is not commutative. And being simple means having no non-trivial proper two-sided ideal in this context. Note that the ring in question simply consists of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries form $k$.